# Error while installing PostgreSQL on CentOS 6.5

Tags: postgresql, centos6.5

I am trying to install `PostgreSQL 9.3` on `CentOS 6.5` with command:

```
rpm -i https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch.rpm
```

But I got an error message:

```
curl: (35) SSL connect error
error: skipping https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch.rpm - transfer failed
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

please also follow this steps :

1- first download rpm file :

```
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch.rpm
```

2- then install it :

```
rpm -ivh pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch.rpm
```

what is the result of these command?